# pyspark connecting to an already existing session

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

On the command line I successfully launch pyspark using `pyspark`
[image]

I suppose that there's now a standalone cluster running locally.
Now I'm trying to connect to this spark session / cluster in my IDE. The problem is that it returns another app id, so I suppose that it has created another cluster / session. How can I use only one cluster from both the shell and my IDE?

```
# connecting to spark interactive
import pyspark
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.applicationId

'local-1690068681515'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting a `SparkSession` with `master("local")` spins up a local cluster, not a Standalone cluster.

A local cluster is a bit of an exception in the sense that it is really 1 single JVM process that runs everything (your driver). If you want to share a cluster running on your machine between different clients (like your pyspark and your IDE) you can do that by spinning up a Standalone cluster.

#### Spinning up a Standalone cluster

If you want to spin up a Standalone cluster you'll need to start up the following:

A master JVM process:

```bash
./$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.sh
```

A worker JVM process

```bash
./$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-worker.sh
```

Now these are running in the background, you're ready to use your cluster.

#### Starting your pyspark REPL with the relevant cluster

```
pyspark --master spark://{hostname}:7077
```

You can find the value of `hostname` by typing `hostname -f` in your command line.

#### Starting your IDE application with the relevant cluster

Now you need to create a `SparkSession` where the relevant master is being used. This can be done like this:

```
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.master("spark://{hostname}:7077").getOrCreate()
```

Again, here you should be using that same `hostname` value as the point above here.

There you go, you're sharing the same cluster!

**One more extra bit of info:** You'll notice that a single cluster will run multiple applications (if you run your `pyspark` REPL and the IDE application .e.g.), so you'll still end up with different application IDs. An application in Spark terms is merely some new "main" function that you're trying to run.

Comment: this worked. Sine I'm on windows I replaced `start-master/worker` scripts by `spark-class` commands
`spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master`
`spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://192.168.0.105:7077`
for some reason the `localhost` was not chosen by the spark master, but rather `192.168.0.105`. Each client also has a separate `app-id` as you mentioned. thanks